# Enlarge one pic onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a website with images on it, and if you click on one of the images it should enlarge. I did that by using the `toggleClass` function in jquery

I enlarged the selected image like so:

```
$(".img1, .img2").on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('enlarged');
});
```

the used class:

```
.enlarged{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
width:500px;
height:600px;
top:-10%;
left:300px;
}
```

it's hard to explain but right now what happens is, when you click an image it enlarges. when you click another image, it enlarges too but overlaps/stays hidden behind the other image that's enlarged.

What I would like to happen is when img1 is enlarged and the user selects img2, it should "close" img1 and enlarge img2.

Thank you :)

**UPDATE**

it now works barely, it opens after spamclicking and once enlarged I can minimize it again. but then I can't enlarge it anymore.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.html .header");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html .footer");

        $("body").on('click', function(){

            if(!$(".img1, .img2").hasClass('enlarged')){

                $(".img1, .img2").on('click',function(){
                    $(this).addClass('enlarged');
                });
            }else{
                $("body").on('click', '.enlarged', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('enlarged');
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following. This will remove the `enlarged` class. Then add it to the image that you have clicked on. (See [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/11612/))

```
$(".img1, .img2").on('click', function() {

  $(".img1, .img2").removeClass("enlarged");
  $(this).toggleClass('enlarged');

});
```

See working example below:

```js
$(".img1, .img2").on('click', function() {
  $(".img1, .img2").removeClass("enlarged");
  $(this).toggleClass('enlarged');
});
```

```css
.enlarged {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  top: -10%;
  left: 300px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img1" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image" />
<img class="img2" src="https://placehold.it/350x150/F2F5A9" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a generic class to all clickable images, like 'gallery'

then

```
$(".gallery").on('click',function(){
    //removes enlarged class from all images
    $(".gallery.enlarged").removeClass('enlarged');
    //adds enlarged class to clicked image
    $(this).addClass('enlarged');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only one "enlarged" class for the img you click on, I think the simpliest is to remove all "enlarged" class then add the class for the right element :

```
$(".img1, .img2").on('click',function(){
    $(".img1, .img2").removeClass('enlarged');
    $(this).addClass('enlarged');
});
```