# Enlarge img on click, click again to minimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website which requires pictures to be clickable. If you click on the image it should enlarge and show in the middle of the screen. If you then click again it should go smaller again and back on its place.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header").load("header.html .header");
    $("#footer").load("footer.html .footer");

    $("body").on('click', function(){

        if(!$(".img1, .img2").hasClass('enlarged')){

            $(".img1, .img2").on('click',function(){
                  $(this).addClass('enlarged');
            });
        }else{
            $("body").on('click', '.enlarged', function(){
                  $(this).removeClass('enlarged');
            });
        }

    });
});
```

```css
.enlarged{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  width:500px;
  height:600px;
  top:-10%;
  left:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container">
  <aside class="aside"><img src="fotos/foto1.JPG" id="img1" class="img1" style="transform:rotate(90deg);"/><img src="fotos/foto2.JPG" class="img2" style="transform:rotate(90deg);"/></aside>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

My current script works but is very wonky. It only enlarges once and you have to triple-click.

I already made a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599906/enlarge-one-pic-onclick/45608114#45608114) about it before, but after I updated nobody answered.

Also I'm not sure how to add images on Stack Overflow, otherwise I would've made a snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click handler isn't actually performing the logic you want, it's just assigning other click handlers.  Then upon further clicks those are performing the logic you want (sort of), but also further assigning more click handlers.  After a couple clicks, this is going to get entirely weird.

You just want *one* click handler for your target elements:

```
$("body").on('click', '.img1, .img2', function(){

});
```

This handler would be invoked for any `.img1` or `.img2` on the page.  Inside this handler, conduct your logic:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('enlarged')) {
    $(this).addClass('enlarged');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('enlarged');
}
```

Or, even simpler:

```
$(this).toggleClass('enlarged');
```

Comment: finally! thank you! sorry for being so late I was busy. I was close to what you have. the thing is, because what I had wasn't working. i started doing illogical things haha. before the toggleClass wouldn't work at all for no reason. now it does so. thanks again! ^^

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are happening in your code:

You first only add a click handler on the `body` element. Which means the 1st time you click on the body it enters your conditional. In your first `if` you add another click handler, but now on `.img1, .img2`. The opposite (removing the `enlarged` class) is again on the `body` element and not on the `.img1, .img2` elements.

Some advice:

- Use only 1 class to toggle the enlarged state
- Personally I'm a big fan of BEM, maybe not relevant for now.
- Split up your JS concerns; I would create a plugin for this behaviour

A bit of code to point you in the right direction:

```
var $elements = $('.enlarge-img');

// in this case not very relevant, but a good habit to have
// a method to instantiate
function initialize() {
  addEventListeners();
}

// adding event listeners
function addEventListeners() {
  $elements.on('click.namespace', handleClick);
  $('body').click('click.namespace', handleClickBody);
}

// You might want to handle clicks on the <body> to remove
// the enlarged state of any image
function handleClickBody(event) {
  $elements.removeClass('enlarge-img--enlarged');     
}

// If you click an image, you want to toggle the enlarged state class
function handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // not necessary on a <img/> but needed if you use a link
  $(event.target).toggleClass('enlarge-img--enlarged`);
}

initialize();
```

Hopefully this helps you in the right direction of creating re-usable code. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I was wondering, what does the line `$elements.on('click.namespace', handleClick);` mean? more specificly what's $elements and why handleClick instead of function? I'm still a student as you probably would've guessed haha. haven't had jquery at school yet.

Comment: `$elements` is set on the 1st line; basically select all elements of a certain class. `$elements.on('click.namespace, handleClick);` adds an event listener to the selected elements and refers to the `handleClick` function. So whenever a user clicks on one of the selected elements, the `handleClick`-method will get called.